# MediaCodec: MediaFormat KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL not working for H264codec

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm setting MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL value as 1 (below given code) but it's not generating Key frame every second but it is generating every 66 second. I'm using Libstreaming library.
can anyone please help why is not working ?

```
mMediaCodec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(debugger.getEncoderName());
  MediaFormat mediaFormat =MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc",
               640,480);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 1000000);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
                debugger.getEncoderColorFormat());
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1); //here
        mMediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null,
                MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mMediaCodec.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the timestamps of your input buffers are in the proper unit (microseconds), and that you on average feed 15 frames per second? Timestamps in the wrong unit is probably the most common cause for this. That would also cause the bitrate of the output stream to be way off what you requested.

If you raise `MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL` to 2 instead of 1, does the keyframe interval raise to 132 seconds from 66? That would indicate an unit error. If it doesn't react at all, it would indicate that the encoder simply doesn't honor this parameter.